# Cycling through a collection of records with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view

I have an array of Questions, stored in `@questions`. I want the user to be able to have next and back buttons to cycle through the questions, using jQuery to change the question div's contents.

So, for example, here's the jQuery code [`.js.erb`] that I would use for the question partial:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#question").html("<strong><%= @question.name %></strong><% insert_more_code_here %>");
});
```

How would I design the page where I want the users to be able to cycle through the questions? I know I would probably be using something in a `each` block but I do not want to show all the questions at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output all of the questions in your HTML and use CSS to hide the ones you don't want to show right away. Then use jQuery to change their visibility either using `jQuery.hide()` and `.show()` or by toggling a CSS class.